# Discovering Memory Leaks in .NET Core using PerfView

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory-leaks, .net-core

I have been trying to track down (what appears to be) a memory leak in an ASP.NET Core application running in Azure. I collected a DMP at the start of the application and a DMP when the memory was at it's peak right before it stalled out and crashed. I am trying to decipher the DMP files using PerfView. I loaded the first dump in, then the second and did a diff. The output of the "By Name" tab looks like this:
[image: Diff of DMPs]

So, question one is: Am I reading this right? Is this telling me there are 18,501 instances of HttpClient? If so, holy crap.

I went in to the "RefTree" tab and this is what I see there:
[image: RefTree]
Sure enough the HttpClient that seems to be taking the bulk is from the LGAuthLib which is my library.

So, what I don't understand is, that HttpClient is a static object allocated once in a static constructor in that class library and then used everywhere. How is it possible to allocate 18,000 of them? Could 18,000 class libraries that house the static object exist? I don't know how that's possible since that object is allocated in a DI singleton.

This is why I am not 100% sure i am reading this Diff correctly. I just can't figure out how that could possibly be leaking.

For the professionals out there who have stared at these things, are you 100% certain the HttpClient object is leaking?

For completeness sake, here is how I am using the HttpClient object:

```
public async Task<string[]> GetRolesForUserByUserNameAsync(string strUser)
{
    var reqParams = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new UriBuilder(_config.ServerUri)
    {
        Path = EndpointGetRolesForUserByMicroService
    }.Uri);
    reqParams.Headers.Add("MicroService", CreateMicroServiceHeaderValue(EndpointGetRolesForUserByMicroService));
    reqParams.Content = HttpClientExtensions.JsonContent(new { userName = strUser });

    using (var resp = await _httpClient.SendAsync(reqParams).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return (await resp.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<string>().ConfigureAwait(false)).Split(',');
    }
}
```

This is how it's being allocated:

```
public sealed class AuthService
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    static AuthService()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are using it is mostly immaterial. If there are 18K instances, we'd need to see how it's being created.

Comment: Updated. I thought maybe not disposing of the `HttpRequestMessage` could cause some issues, so that's why i added that

Comment: If I'm seeing those *tiny* images correctly, I think what you're looking at is the inclusive and exclusive sample counts. Any kind of profiler uses sampling to do the analysis, whether it's CPU cycles or heap allocation. Can you clarify what makes you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: you can click on the images and it should show you the full size. I am not sure if represents a memory leak or not. That's what my question is -- what information can be taken from PerfView?

Comment: A *LOT*, and really, too much to try to explain it all here. If I recall correctly, there are little "?" links to explain the column information.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield could you share some good articles on that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating to .NET Core 3.0+ fixed this. It must have been an issue in the framework.